# SonarQube: How do I compare arbitrary versions?

Tags: sonarqube

At the top of the SonarCube page for my project there is a drop down box to access deltas - but I can only choose "since previous analysis", and "over 30 days". As I have a very slow developing project, like a version every two months, the 30-days choice is of no use for me at all, and this drop down boils down to two versions.

What I need is to compare any two arbitrary versions of the project (that Sonar analysed before). Is this possible? How?

Note: Currently I run SonarQube 4.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like what you can read on the [documentation of the differential view feature](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Differential+Views) of SonarQube, you can achieve this using the "period 4" or "period 5" properties at project level, and specify a version to compare to.

Note that you can update the analysis history of your project to add versions on specific analyses, as described on the [History and Events documentation page](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Historical+Information).

Comment: Ah. And it only worked **after** I made Sonar run over the code again.